# How to import multiple postgres databases using single file in another ubuntu installation?

Tags: 16.04, backup, postgresql, database, migration

Is there a way to move all databases from Pgadmin 3 one ubuntu installation to another.

I have created a big dump (a single file to export all database from one system). Now I want to import that big file in my pgadmin3 or in console in postgres.

Is there a way to get this accomplished? Both installation has same versions and OS numbers.

Both has Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Postgres 9.5 installed.

Any better way to get that done please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do what you ask is to run as the database superuser (postgresql)

```
 pg_dumpall >file
```

from one postgresql cluster (all the databases on a system) into a file, then simply import the file with

```
psql  
 \i file
```

or

```
psql -f file postgresql
```

Read the manual for pg_dumpall

```
man pg_dumpall
```

To change defaults like ports if necessary.

The dump contains all the database, table and user recreations needed, as well as the data itself.  Afterward, the manual suggest running

```
vacuumdb -a -z
```

to help out the optimizer.

---

You can select a single database to dump/backup with pg_dump.  You might play around with the -l argument to pg_dumpall to select another database which contains only the databases of interest, but I've never done that.  Or just edit the output file with everything and remove what you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

For example, you can export everything such as all databases, users(roles), etc to `backup.sql` with  [pg_dumpall](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-dumpall.html) as shown below. *You better use any superusers(e.g., `postgres`) to do it smoothly without permission errors and `pg_dumpall` can output SQL in only plain text format rather than custom format or tar format and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984733/postgresql-export-database-to-sql-file/77251389#77251389) explains how to export schema and data with [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) and [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-ALL) explains how to export and import with `pg_dumpall`:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres -f backup.sql
```

Or, you can export everything except the data of all databases to `backup.sql` as shown below:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres -s > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres --schema-only > backup.sql
```

Or, you can export everything except the schema of all databases to `backup.sql` with only `INSERT` statement which has column names as shown below:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres -a --column-inserts > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres --data-only --column-inserts > backup.sql
```

Then, you will need to input multiple passwords after running the command above:

```
Password: 
Password: 
Password:
...
```

Then, you can import `backup.sql`(everything) into your PostgreSQL as shown below.

```
psql -U postgres -f backup.sql
```

Or, you can try this below which doesn't work on Windows:

```
psql -U postgres < backup.sql
```

Or, you can import `backup.sql`(everything) into your PostgreSQL with `\i` after login with the user(role) `postgres` as shown below:

```
psql -U postgres
postgres=# \i backup.sql
```

Or, you can import `backup.sql` into multiple databases one by one as shown below. *You have to create each database (and the schema to import only data) before hand otherwise there is error and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641512/create-database-from-command-line-in-postgresql/77263012#77263012) explains how to create a database and you must use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) to import SQL in plain text format rather than [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) which can import SQL in custom format or tar format and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732474/restore-a-postgres-backup-file-using-the-command-line/77275771#77275771) explains how to import `backup.sql` into `orange` database:

```
psql -U postgres -f backup.sql orange
psql -U postgres -f backup.sql lemon
psql -U postgres -f backup.sql peach
...
```

In addition, you can export all databases to `backup.sql` without multiple password prompts by setting a password(e.g., `banana`) to [PGPASSWORD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html#id-1.7.3.22.3.4.6.1.1) as shown below:

```
PGPASSWORD=banana pg_dumpall -U postgres > backup.sql
```

And, you can export all databases excluding `orange` and `*apple*` databases to `backup.sql` as shown below. *Multiple `--exclude-database` are available in one command:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres --exclude-database=orange --exclude-database=*apple* > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
pg_dumpall -U postgres --exclude-database orange --exclude-database *apple* > backup.sql
```